# How to Invite attendees in google calendar cli

Tags: ubuntu, google-calendar-api

I have installed google's cli (gcalcli) for adding and retrieving calendar events. Is there a way to add participants to an event using the gcalcli . Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the program currently supports editing an event's attendees. I would recommend either requesting the program's author to add this functionality or extending the program yourself. You would use the Google Calendar API method [Events.update](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) to change the attendee list of an existing event.